# How to determine when a canvas has finished loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

So I was making a rather large canvas that was filled with 1x1 pixels, and I wanted to make a loading screen for it. The problem after the loop filling the canvas finishes, it alerts that it has finished loading, but the canvas has not actually changed. I made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ec4mB/) here to demonstrate. How do I actually find out when the canvas has actually loaded using javascript or Jquery, and what is causing this behavior?

```
var ctx=document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
for(var x=1;x<600;x++){
    for(var y=1;y<600;y++){
        var color= '#' + Math.floor (Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
        ctx.fillStyle=color;
        ctx.fillRect(x,y,1,1);
    }
}
alert('done!');
```

Comment: I don't know about you, but the alert does fire after you filled noise in the canvas. Works fine. It could be the browser, where it fires the alert before it renders the canvas, since `alert` does block the UI.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer It certainly doesn't for me. Not sure why it does that.

Comment: @scrblnrd3 browser, version and OS?

Comment: Chrome on Mac OSX Mountain lion

Comment: @scrblnrd3 I have Chrome 26 on Windows. Can you check on other browsers?

Comment: edit: What actually happens is when i click the alertbox, it will update the canvas right after.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ec4mB/2/ - if you remove the alert from the "thread" with a settimeout, it fires properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Since you said jquery was ok, just fire a custom event when the loops are done looping.**

Any code that needs the canvas fully loaded can go in the event handler.

```
// Listen for custom CanvasOnLoad event
$(document).on( "CanvasOnLoad", canvasOnLoadHandler ); 

var ctx=document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');

for(var x=1;x<600;x++){
    for(var y=1;y<600;y++){
        var color= '#' + Math.floor (Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
        ctx.fillStyle=color;
        ctx.fillRect(x,y,1,1);
    }

    // fire CanvasOnLoad when the looping is done
    if(x>=599){
        $.event.trigger({
          type: "CanvasOnLoad"
          });
    }

}
console.log("...follows the for loops.");

// handle CanvasOnLoad knowing your canvas has fully drawn
function canvasOnLoadHandler(){
    console.log("canvas is loaded");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is just like a load-progress animation. Updating/advancing that animation from a running function usually doesn't work right away (screen updates when that function finishes).

Your canvas-code is (automatically) wrapped in a `onload` function: `window.onload=function(){ /*your code here*/ };`.
The last line of that function is `alert('done!');`, so naturally you'll get the alertbox before the screen updates and you see the noize.

One solution is to first one set and display's a loading-image, then using a `setTimeOut` (say 30ms) one renders the canvas, ending that canvas-function with another setTimeOut to remove the loading-image again.

Note: as you probably know, your code will generate (a lot of) hex-colors like `#3df5` and `#5d8a6`, both of which aren't valid colors! Also you used 16777215, but Math.random() needs to be multiplied by 16777216. To fix this, you might want to try:
`color='#'+((Math.random()+1)*16777216|0).toString(16).substr(1);`
[Here](http://paulirish.com/2009/random-hex-color-code-snippets/) is some good read about random colors.

See this JSFiddle [result](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ETQuu/show/) as an example.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't see your point regarding the variable `color`. It looks fine to me. The variable declaration is hoisted to the start of the function anyway, moving it changes nothing.

Comment: @dystroy: I updated my answer accordingly. However, *in my opinion* jslint/crockford is right: one shouldn't re-declare variables anyway.

Comment: The variable is, in fact, only declared once. Moving the var declaration isn't bad practice.

Comment: note that the global scope counts as a "function". The `onLoad` wrapping has no effect in terms of UI blocking.